# libvlc: Error loading script http.lua

Tags: c, lua, video-streaming, vlc, libvlc

I downloaded vlc-2.2.1 source code and compiled it after a long struggle. Now, when I run it as ./vlc from the source directory, it shows the following error and vlc window does not show up.

```
VLC media player 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax) (revision 2.2.1-0-ga425c42)
[08258920] [http] lua interface error: Error loading script /home/ezio/vlcLib/vlc-2.2.1/share/lua/intf/http.luac: /home/ezio/vlcLib/vlc-2.2.1/share/lua/intf/http.luac: bad header in precompiled chunk
[081a2b18] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[082338b0] [cli] lua interface error: Error loading script /home/ezio/vlcLib/vlc-2.2.1/share/lua/intf/cli.luac: /home/ezio/vlcLib/vlc-2.2.1/share/lua/intf/cli.luac: bad header in precompiled chunk
```

I needed the web interface functionality of vlc. So, I configured ~/.config/vlc/vlcrc as

```
#### Extra interface modules (string)
extraintf=http
```

How can I fix this error ?

NOTE:
I have vlc 2.1.6 installed in my computer,
it works fine

```
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
[0x8fd3718] [http] lua interface: Lua HTTP interface
[0x8fc3910] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
"sni-qt/29618" WARN  13:36:25.965 void StatusNotifierItemFactory::connectToSnw() Invalid interface to SNW_SERVICE
```